# Offline capability in web app with sync when online

Tags: google-sheets, offline

I need to give a survey  to people on a tablet device. The survey runs on a browser which might often disconnect from the internet, hence I need to have the device sync whenever its in the wifi network. Is it possible with Google forms? Which other choices do I have?

Answer (score 2):

Google docs can do this now!

Click the gear icon that says Settings, and you should see "Set up Docs offline beta"

Comment: Each of the clients must have that set up. However, Forms work differently and no data will be submitted without Internet access.